# Generating GraphQL for existing DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm new to using AWS Amplify and trying to add an existing DynamoDB table.

I understand I can use the `amplify import storage` to import the existing DynamoDB table. I would like to add a GraphQL api to query the table and return results to the frontend.

When I use `amplify add api` is there anyway to get the schema generated automatically from the DynamoDB table, or do I have to write it out myself? Alternatively, should I instead create a new AppSync that can [generate the schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/import-dynamodb.html), and import that into Amplify?

I'm less clear about importing existing AppSync resources - [is this the direction I should take](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/existing-resources/q/platform/js/)?

Answer (score 0):

To generate GraphQL for an existing Amazon DynamoDB table, look at using AWS AppSync. That will let you interact with the Amazon DynamoDB table using GraphQL commands. To learn how to do this, look at this AWS documentation.

[Launch your first GraphQL API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/quickstart-launch-a-sample-schema.html)

Comment: Thanks - once I have this launched, can I add it to my Amplify project? By using the second link in my question.